# Django rest framework incorrect nested serialization

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I started a new django rest framework project and bumped into an annoying problem. The nested serialization doesn't work as expected. Instead of serializing relationship models and returning serialized object it returns an extra "relationship" field in addition to defaul "attributes" json field.

Here is my python 3.6 code:

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='User', null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('First name', max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last name', max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField('Phone number', max_length=15)
    activated = models.DateTimeField('Activated')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<Profile {self.first_name.title()} {self.last_name.title()}>'
```

## serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Profile

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username', 'profile')
```

## views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .models import Profile


class UserViews(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The answer I expect to get:

```
{
        "data": [
            {
                "type": "UserViews",
                "id": "1",
                "attributes": {
                    "email": "",
                    "username": "admin",
                    "profile": {
                         "id": 1,
                         "first_name": "name1",
                         "last_name": "name2",
                         "phone_number": "+79999999999",
                     }
                },
            }
        ]
    }
```

What I actually get:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "UserViews",
            "id": "1",
            "attributes": {
                "email": "",
                "username": "admin"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "profile": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "Profile",
                        "id": "1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What's the problem and how can I fix that? I copied this code from my previous project where everything was ok. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The code you provided would not return the result you posted. You removed the broken code while writing the question and therefore there's nothing we can do.

Comment: Nah, I didn't remove anything. With the provided code the result is still incorrect.

Comment: By default your response matching the code would be: `[{"id": "1", "email": "", "username": "admin", "profile": {"id": "1", "first_name": "name1", "last_name": "name2", "phone_number": "+79999999999"}}]` Maybe you have some 3rd parties installed that rewrites the response but what you provide is not django rest framework default response.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. It was the views.py file, not the serializers.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out I made an extremely dumb mistake. All I had to do to get the right response is just replace the 
`return Response(serializer.data)` line to `return Response({'info': serializer.data})` line inside the **views.py** file.